# Broken Packages on Pop!_OS (Dependency Problems)

Tags: package-management, dependencies

So I recently tried updating all my packages to prepare to update to Pop!_OS 22.04, which is what it says on the system76 website.

I ran `sudo apt update` which gave this output:

```
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://apt.pop-os.org/proprietary jammy InRelease
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
Hit:4 http://apt.pop-os.org/release jammy InRelease      
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Fetched 110 kB in 2s (61.2 kB/s)
appstreamcli: symbol lookup error: appstreamcli: undefined symbol: AS_SYSTEM_COLLECTION_METADATA_PATHS
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
1139 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

Now on running `sudo apt upgrade`, it gives this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 evolution-data-server : Depends: libedataserver-1.2-26 (= 3.40.4-1ubuntu1) but 3.44.0-2 is installed
 libebackend-1.2-10 : Depends: libedataserver-1.2-26 (= 3.40.4-1ubuntu1) but 3.44.0-2 is installed
 libebook-1.2-20 : Depends: libedataserver-1.2-26 (= 3.40.4-1ubuntu1) but 3.44.0-2 is installed
 libebook-contacts-1.2-3 : Depends: libedataserver-1.2-26 (= 3.40.4-1ubuntu1) but 3.44.0-2 is installed
 libecal-2.0-1 : Depends: libedataserver-1.2-26 (= 3.40.4-1ubuntu1) but 3.44.0-2 is installed
 libedata-book-1.2-26 : Depends: libedataserver-1.2-26 (= 3.40.4-1ubuntu1) but 3.44.0-2 is installed
 libedata-cal-2.0-1 : Depends: libedataserver-1.2-26 (= 3.40.4-1ubuntu1) but 3.44.0-2 is installed
 libedataserverui-1.2-3 : Depends: libedataserver-1.2-26 (= 3.40.4-1ubuntu1) but 3.44.0-2 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

On running `sudo apt --fix-broken install`, this outputs:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  cryptsetup-run gcc-11-base:i386 libcamel-1.2-62 libgphoto2-l10n libgranite5 libllvm13:i386 libomp5-13 libperl5.32 libperl5.32:i386 libssl1.1:i386 libwebp6:i386 ltrace perl-modules-5.32
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  evolution-data-server libebackend-1.2-10 libebook-1.2-20 libebook-contacts-1.2-3 libecal-2.0-1 libedata-book-1.2-26 libedata-cal-2.0-1 libedataserverui-1.2-3
Suggested packages:
  evolution
The following packages will be upgraded:
  evolution-data-server libebackend-1.2-10 libebook-1.2-20 libebook-contacts-1.2-3 libecal-2.0-1 libedata-book-1.2-26 libedata-cal-2.0-1 libedataserverui-1.2-3
8 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1131 not upgraded.
190 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,685 kB of archives.
After this operation, 30.7 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on libpcre3; however:
  Package libpcre3:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on libpcre3; however:
  Package libpcre3:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on libpcre3; however:
  Package libpcre3:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on libpcre3; however:
  Package libpcre3:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on libpcre3; however:
  Package libpcre3:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386:
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on libpcre3; however:
  Package libpcre3:i386 is not configured yet.


(*The message above was repeated around 20-ish times*)


dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 libglib2.0-0:i386
 libglib2.0-0:i386
 libglib2.0-0:i386
 libglib2.0-0:i386

(*This also was repeated aboout 20 times*)
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Now i cannot install, purge, reinstall any packages, or run `sudo apt autoremove`.

Any help would be immensely appreciated.

PS: I know people have had similar problems before but I haven't been able to fix the issue with those solutions (or I may just be dumb).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I did to fix my issue was to run `dpkg` and reconfigure all packages.

```bsh
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Reboot, then I was able to finish upgrading my system.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I had this issue and I fixed it. If you do not have Synaptic Package Manager installed you need to install it.

When you open Synaptic Package Manager, go To status, broken. There you will see the broken packages.
Click on the first one, edit and force version and install version 1.2-26.

After you do this you will be able to upgrade successfully and broken packages will be fixed. I had this issue for a few days and yesterday I was able to fix it and upgrade to 22.04.

Comment: This did not work for me. Pop Shop and apt both barf on themselves with the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in terminal:

```
sudo apt clean  
sudo apt update -m  
sudo dpkg --configure -a  
sudo apt install -f  
sudo apt dist-upgrade  
sudo apt autoremove --purge
```